# How often does WordPress check for updates?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can someone tell me how to check how often WordPress checks for updates?

Does the check for update depend on user interactions? for instance if my website has zero traffic and zero user interaction, is WordPress still able to check for updates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There is also a dedicated page for updates which can be reached from
>   the dashboard menu. It’s helpful when you want to do bulk updates of
>   multiple plugins instead of updating each one separately. It also has
>   a “Check Again” button which checks for new updates. By default,
>   **WordPress does this check every 12 hours**.
>
> **The 12 hour waiting period is defined in WordPress core on Line 147 of
>   the wp-includes/update.php file, it’s the $timeout variable.**

[source](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-http-api-automatic-plugin-updates/)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress has a built-in cron event called `wp_update_plugins`. This runs `Twice Daily` (every 12 hours). Note, this does not mean at Midnight and Noon. It depends on when the install was created and/or the last time the cron event ran. [Source](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_plugins/)

Since this *plugin update check* is relying on **WP-Cron**, it would therefore depend on user traffic to cause the **WP-Cron** to trigger the event (since it only runs on page load). [Source](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/)

As @F0G mentioned, you can manually check for plugin and theme updates by going to:

- `Dashboard > Updates > Check Again`